# Conditional branches using tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having problems calculating the gradient using the gradient tape when using a `tf.function` with conditional branches.

Inside a gradient tape scope, I am trying to calculate the gradient of `z` w.r.t `self.LMn`. This works perfectly fine when I do not annotate the function with `@tf.function`. The error originates in a subclassed `tf.keras.layers.Layer` call function:

```
def call(self, x, training=None, labels=None, cur_switch=None, basis_filters=None):
    if basis_filters is None:
        basis_filters = self.initial_basis_filters

    gap = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=[1, 2])
    z = tf.einsum('bc,cd->bd', gap, self.LMn)

    # ... code for out

    return out, z
```

The actual error is given as follows:

```
....
C:\...\ops\cond_v2.py:387 <lambda>
    lambda: _grad_fn(func_graph, grads), [], {},
C:\...\ops\cond_v2.py:363 _grad_fn
    assert len(func_graph.outputs) == len(grads)

AssertionError:
```

More specifically,

```
func_graphs.outputs = [<tf.Tensor 'vgg16/block1a/block1a_conv/cond_2/Identity:0' shape=(128, 32, 32, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'vgg16/block1a/block1a_conv/cond_2/OptionalFromValue:0' shape=() dtype=variant>, <tf.Tensor 'vgg16/block1a/block1a_conv/cond_2/OptionalFromValue_1:0' shape=() dtype=variant>]
```

and

```
grads = (<tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/vgg16/block1a/block1a_conv/strided_slice_3/StridedSliceGrad_1:0' shape=(128, 32, 32, None) dtype=float32>,)
```

I can assume that each of these outputs corresponds to the cases for some set of conditional branches outputs that are then fed into the `tf.einsum` function. I have read over all of the edge cases and precautions in the gradient tape documentation as this seems to the problem. Just a note that I am only performing conditional computation using hyperparameters (passed into `tf.function` as pythonic variables, such as `basis_filters`). There are also some conditional branches using (tensorflow ops) functions of these hyperparameters, is this allowed? or do I need to compute these values outside `tf.function` and pass these in as pythonic variables too?

I know the question is not completely clear and I can provide any extra information if needed. It would very helpful to have some guidance on what to look for with this kind of problem.

Thanks!

Comment: i have a similar issue. did you figure this out?